# Can't update on 18.04 - repository change

Tags: package-management, updates

```
Αγνόησε:5 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease          
Φέρε:6 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Release [956 B]                
Φέρε:7 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Release.gpg [481 B] 
Hit:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Ανάγνωση Λιστών Πακέτων... Ολοκληρώθηκε
E: Repository 'https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'manual_build' to 'obs://private/DEB/xUbuntu_18.04'
E: Repository 'https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Release' changed its 'Codename' value from 'Bionic' to 'xUbuntu_18.04'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

What do I do now, and how?

Answer (score 12):

Try using `apt` instead of `apt-get`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Alternatively, `apt-get` can accept the changes with

```
sudo apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update
```

Comment: This worked for me but I don't understand why. When I tried apt-get update, it failed, but when I did apt update, it prompted to confirm the change in release info. So is it just that only apt can confirm the changes and apt-get specifically needs --allow-releaseinfo-change ?